# Is there an R function to find the highest value in a column among the rows that share the value of another column?

Tags: r

So basically I have a dataframe with the following data:

```
 **State**    **District**                                   **Number of Cases**
 1 Sarawak     Sarikei                                           11
 2 Perak       K.Kangsar                                         10
 3 Selangor    Bukit Raja                                        18
 4 Selangor    Bukit Raja                                         8
 5 Selangor    Petaling                                          19
 6 Selangor    Petaling                                           9
 7 Selangor    Hulu Langat                                        6
 8 Selangor    Petaling                                          21
 9 Selangor    Petaling                                           9
10 Selangor    Petaling                                           8
```

I want to find the district with the highest number of cases in each state

Comment: You have the same district duplicated many times for a given state, what do you want to do in this case? Do you sum the district cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count the number of cases in each district of the state and keep the row with max value in each state.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(State, District) %>%
  summarise(Number_of_Cases = sum(Number_of_Cases)) %>%
  slice(which.max(Number_of_Cases)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice_max` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(State, District) %>%
   summarise(Number_of_Cases = sum(Number_of_Cases, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Number_of_Cases)
```